# custom fontFamily for textview giving Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, fonts

Well I'm tring to change a textview font family to a custom font 
I used [this documentation from Google](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html)

But my app crash at launch Well here is what i did exactly

I created an Android resource directory and I added my font to it (using windows explorer)
[Here is a screenshot of that directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZyZ5.png)

Then I created an Android resource file named myfont in that directory here here is its content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/droidkufi_regular" />
</font-family>
```

Ps: the font file name is droidkufi_regular.ttf (it was with upper case letter but i changed it to lower case)

Than here is my text view

```
<TextView
.
.
android:fontFamily="@font/myfont"
.
.
/>
```

I run the app every things looks good on the gradle build but when the app launch on my phone It crash ("App Name" has stopped) I also tried restarting my phone, clearing the app data, reinstall, and also installing the app on an emulator.

well here is the logcat:
in pastebin since it kinda long
(packagename is com.mypackagename)
https://pastebin.com/cjh67DZm

NB: this only happens with custom fonts, when I use a system font like this:
android:fontFamily="cursive"
It works as supposed.

Comment: post your java code what you do with textview?

Comment: The java code is fine when i use another system font like cursive,monospace,.. it works

Comment: i think it's not font issue. that's why i am asked you to post your code may i know what value you set in textview?

Comment: That text view that I'm testing on is showing the app name on a navigation drawer it works as i said when i use system fonts and its value (appname) is in english so no encoding problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use both :

```
android:font="@font/yourFont"
```

and :

```
app:font="@font/yourfont"
```